# Adding a new column with month extracted from a separate already existing "date" (mdy) column

Tags: r, date, datatable, lubridate

[image: a partial clip of the data set]

Trying to add a new column in my data table denoting the month (either as a numeric value or character) using an already available column of "SetDate", which is in the format mdy.

I'm new to R and having trouble. Thank you

Comment: Please do no use pictures of code. Inclue the data in a reproducible form, eg using `dput(data)` and includng the output

Answer (score 1):

`base` solution:

```
f = "%m/%d/%y" # note the lowercase y; it's because the year is 92, not 1992
dataset$SetDateMonth <- format(as.POSIXct(dataset$SetDate, format = f), "%m")
```

Basically, what it does is it converts the column from `character` (presumed class) to `POSIXct`, which allows for an easy extraction of month information.

Quick test:

```
format(as.POSIXct('1/1/92', format = "%m/%d/%y"), "%m")
[1] "01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (created a small example):

```
library(lubridate)

date_example <- "1/1/92"
lubridate::mdy(date_example)
[1] "1992-01-01"
lubridate::mdy(date_example) %>% lubridate::month()
[1] 1
```

If you want full month as character string, use:

```
lubridate::mdy(date_example) %>% lubridate::month(label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```